# В данном контексте употребить цен или цены?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Перечень услуг с указанием цены (цен) размещается на сайте.

Answer (score 2):

Перечень услуг с указанием цен  размещается на сайте.

Речь идет об ***услугах*** (мн. число), поэтому используется форма мн. числа ***цен.***

Пример: http://77.rospotrebnadzor.ru/index.php/napravlenie/zpp/2175-zpp

Перечень платных медицинских **услуг** (прейскурант) с указанием **цен** в рублях

Answer (score 0):

> Перечень услуг с указанием цены (цен) размещается на сайте.

Перечень услуг и их стоимости см. на сайте.

(Цена подразумевает фиксированную и стабильную величину; услуга, состоящая из многих операций, часто непредвиденных и требующих неясных заранее временных затрат, не может иметь оговорённой суммарной цены.)